# Bootstrap javascript or popover not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Got a Problem with my Bootstrap. It seems as if the JS is not working correctly somehow, because even the easiest examples of popovers dont work. (http://jsfiddle.net/weuWk/363/)
This little piece of code which works correctly on JSFiddle, is just creating a Button(w/o hover functionality) if used in my source code.

The Modal-Plugin is actually working, so this should mean that i include the js files in the right way. I will copy it anyway:

```
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: check console for errors, i'd be willing to bet there is one

Comment: Seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: like what Mike said. Any errors in your console? You know what console is?

Comment: y, I've just found out how to view the console for js

Answer (score 15, accepted):

jQuery needs to be included before bootstrap's javascript, as bootstrap is just jQuery "plugins".

You should Include in this order:

1. jQuery
2. Bootstrap
3. Your Javascript

**EDIT: Try this right before the closing body tag**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
    $('#test').popover();​
});
 </script>
```

Also, the console is your friend. Check and make sure there are no errors.

SOLVED:

Solution: > Right order of Includes > fixing errors i got from my js console.

Comment: if this is the problem - there is a console error "$" not defined in bootstrap.min.js

Comment: I've changed the order of those two includes and it still doesnt work tho'.

Comment: Also, he mentioned the Model's working, but not the popover. Its possible that the model could work with the direction he is including, as a model generated off a user action would happen after The "$" variable was defined by jquery, where the bootstrap popovers events are trying to happen while the DOM is loading.

Comment: @user1911283 - Where are you including bootstrap and jquery (header or before the closing `</body>` tag?, and where are you calling `$('#test').popover();​`?) Look at the update in my answer.

Comment: @user1911283 - I noticed you edited my answer and said it was solved. Would you be so kind as to mark my answer as correct that that future readers may find it useful? Thanks!